# Deploying on Rinkeby with Truffle using infura

Tags: truffle, metamask, rinkeby, infura

If I want to use `HDWalletProvider` to deploy my contract on a specific address, what should I do?

```
rinkeby: { 
    provider: () => { return new HDWalletProvider("Mnemnoic", "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/KEY") }, 
    network_id: 4, 
    gas: 7003605, 
    gasPrice: 21, 
    host: "localhost", 
    from: "0xdc18ee70c6215ac9c81a3f704648b8c8a6ec7201"
}
```

I am getting following error

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually. 
Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address: "0xdc18ee70c6215ac9c81a3f704648b8c8a6ec7201"
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say _deploy my contract on specific address_? In your example the _host_ and the _from_ value are not necessary

Answer (score 1):

According to the truffle-hdwallet people, the issue is likely because it's not the first account generated with that mnemonic. If you look at the mnemonic on different networks, it's the same.

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/issues/7

I had the same problem. Removed the from and it resolved that error. HD Wallet can figure out the from address by the mnemonic

Answer (score 1):

```
rinkeby: { 
    provider: () => { return new HDWalletProvider("Mnemnoic", "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/KEY") }, 
    network_id: 4, 
    gas: 7003605, 
    gasPrice: 21, 
    host: "localhost", 
    from: "0xdc18ee70c6215ac9c81a3f704648b8c8a6ec7201"
}
```

Rinkeby's network_id should be 4 as I remember but you give the infura link for Ropsten?
"https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/KEY"?
I am not sure if they have any relationships for your error

Comment: Please ask a new question, if this post is related include the link.